# Is there a way to automatically apply capitalization rules in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-office, automation, text-formatting, microsoft-word-2016

In MS Word, is there a way to automatically capitalize titles or headlines, after one of the commonly used capitalization rules, like you can find them here: https://capitalizemytitle.com?

The most ideal solution would be, that when I set a headline to one of my headline templates, it will automatically capitalize it correctly (using the Chicago styleguide for instance).

Can this be done somehow in MS Word? I'm using MS Word Professional Plus 2016.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are Styles and you can not apply the option *Capitalize Each Word* for styles because it can not be selected in the *Customize or create new styles* dialogs . A possible solution is to link a macro to your headline styles that does the capitalization whenever it finds an appearance of your Headline style template. This is also said in https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/26284-customising-style-uses-title-case-formatting.html :

> This [*Capitalize Each Word*] cannot be applied as a Style. It is not a formatting option but
>   rather a command
>
> You likely could create a macro that would search through a document
>   looking for a particular style and applying a true title case to that
>   Style. Graham Mayor has a macro [http://www.gmayor.com/word_vba_examples_2.htm ] for True Title Case in English that
>   may help as a start.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished via:

1. **File** > *Options*
2. **Proofing** - ***AutoCorrect Options*** - *AutoCorrect Options...*

   1. **AutoCorrect** > *Replace text as you type*
   2. **AutoFormat As You Type** > *Define styles based on your formatting*

Comment: I think this doesn't quite do, what I am looking for. There I would have to type in every existing word and define it's capitalization. And how do I make it, so that it only applies on titles and headlines?